# How to execute Robotframework scripts in jmeter for performance testing.

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

We want to test windows app and through Jmeter we are not able to record the application so we will record it in robotframework tool and execute it in Jmeter. Kindly suggest us how we can do that as we have only these 2 tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can record Windows application network activity using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) when the application uses (surprisingly) the next protocols:

- [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/http)
- [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https)

If you are sure that your application uses one of these (or both) protocols you **can** record it using JMeter, just double check the following:

1. Configure your application to use JMeter as a proxy. If the application doesn't have proxy settings it might respect [Windows global proxy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)#BKMK_2)
2. You might need to install [Loopback adapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708322(v=ws.10).aspx)
3. You might need to install [JMeter's self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-certmgr-to-install-test-certificates-on-a-test-computer)

See [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more information on recording and replaying desktop applications network activity using JMeter.

As a last resort you can always run anything including [Robot framework tests from command line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id142) using JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) (but in this case each JMeter thread - virtual user - will trigger a new instance of tests which can be very resource intensive)

Comment: But how we can launch the desktop application  by using HTTP or HTTPs protocol if it is not web based application.